# Is there a shared variable between tasks in same executor

Tags: apache-spark

Accumulators and broadcast variables is a way of having shared variables in all nodes of cluster. Although, there are restrictions in their usage.

I am looking for a type of shared variable that lives in an executor and each task running in that executor can update and read it. Each executor may have a different instance of that type, so nothing will be transmitted over network. Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On JVM**

Yes. Every singleton object can act as "shared variable". This of course requires some form of synchronization if *executor can update and read it*, and as a result, it might be a serious bottleneck.

Also, if updates are not idempotent, you cannot guarantee correctness if task is recomputed.

**In Python**

No. Each worker runs in a separate process and there is no shared memory.